# perform grails each asynchronously

Tags: grails, asynchronous

I would like this to be performed asynchronously

```
    Map someotherMap = [{"10","dance"},{"2","stop"}]
    Map resultMap = [:]
    someotherMap.each { key, value ->
       doSomethingThatsAddsToResultMap(key,value,resultMap)
    }
```

Then I can use resultMap as I wish.

I have tried

```
    Map resultMap = [:]
    Map someotherMap = [{"10","dance"},{"2","stop"}]
    GParsPool.withPool {
        someotherMap.eachParallel { key,value  ->
            doSomethingThatsAddsToResultMap(key,value,resultMap)
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas how I could get this working?

Comment: what is the result now?

Comment: Looks about right to me - as @injecteer says, what happens when you run it? Any errors?

Comment: It turned out to be a different error. Thanks for your help anyway. I will leave this post up as it could help others.